# How can I work around this MapKit bug that causes duplicate callouts?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, mapkit

There's a [bug in MapKit that can cause duplicate callout views on an annotation](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5579596644745216). If the timing is just right, an annotation view can get re-used while it is being selected and apparently just before the callout view is actually added to it. As a result, the old callout view gets stuck there, and the new callout will appear on top of or next to it. Here's what this can look like in an OS X app:

[image]

There's only one annotation on this map. If you click elsewhere on the map to deselect the annotation, only one of the callouts disappears. In some cases you might have two callouts with completely different information, which is where things get really confusing for someone using your app.

Here's the majority of a sample OS X project I put together that illustrates this bug:

```
@import MapKit;
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "JUNMapAnnotation.h"

@interface AppDelegate () <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property BOOL firstPin;

- (void)placeAndSelectPin;
- (JUNMapAnnotation *)placePin;
- (void)clearPins;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (IBAction)dropSomePins:(id)sender {
    self.firstPin = YES;
    [self placeAndSelectPin];
    [self performSelector:@selector(placeAndSelectPin) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0001];
}

#pragma mark - Private methods

- (void)placeAndSelectPin {
    [self clearPins];
    JUNMapAnnotation *annotation = [self placePin];
    [self.mapView deselectAnnotation:annotation animated:NO];
    [self.mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
}

- (JUNMapAnnotation *)placePin {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50.0,50.0);
    JUNMapAnnotation *annotation = [[JUNMapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord];
    annotation.title = @"Annotation";
    annotation.subtitle = (self.firstPin) ? @"This is an annotation with a longer subtitle" : @"This is an annotation";
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    self.firstPin = NO;
    return annotation;
}

- (void)clearPins {
    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
}

#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[JUNMapAnnotation class]]) {

        static NSString *identifier = @"annotationView";
        MKPinAnnotationView *view = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (view == nil) {
            view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
            view.canShowCallout = YES;
            NSLog(@"new annotation view");
        } else {
            view.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return view;

    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

The same bug seems to exist in iOS, though I've had a tougher time recreating it there.

While I'm waiting on Apple to fix this, I'd like to work around it as much as possible. So far I've come up with a few possibilities:

1. Don't re-use annotation views. From what I can tell this seems like the only way to completely avoid the bug, but it seems pretty inefficient.
2. When an annotation view is re-used in `mapView:viewForAnnotation:`, remove all of its subviews. Currently it seems like the callout is the only subview, though it doesn't seem like a particularly safe hack. It also only sort of works—it doesn't prevent duplicate callouts from appearing, it just keeps them from sticking around forever. (When this bug first happens, there actually aren't any subviews yet.)
3. Combine both of those: if `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:` returns a view that has any subviews, ignore it and create a new one. This seems a lot safer than 2 and isn't nearly as inefficient as 1. But as with 2 it's not a complete workaround.

I've also tried adding `deselectAnnotation:animated:` in every place I can think of, but I can't find anything that works. I assume that once the annotation view is re-used, the MapView loses track of the first callout, so none of its normal methods will get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

this is a bit out of left field, but..
try registering the same cell class with 2 different reuse identifiers. in `viewForAnnotation:`, alternate between using each identifier when dequeueing a cell. this should prevent grabbing from the same queue twice in succession.

Comment: Interestingly, this worked in my OS X test app, where I was previously able to recreate the bug every time. But then I tried the same thing on iOS and I was able to recreate the bug immediately. Bummer. Great idea though!

Comment: `viewForAnnotation:` is probably getting called on different threads.  you may want to try wrapping a `@synchronized(self)` around everything in the method.